# Error: Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to display Agendas from table "tblAgenda" using Asp.net here is the query:

```
public static List<int> SelectByYear()
    {
        DbManager db = new DbManager();
        try
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            var result = from p in db.tblAgenda
                         group p by p.News.Value.Year
                             into g
                             select new { Year = g.Key, Releases = g };
            foreach (var obj in result)
            {
                list.Add(obj.Year);
            }
            list.Reverse();
            return list.ToList<int>();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

and here I am calling the above method:

```
public partial class edd_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
            {
                RecentData();
            }
        }
    }

    private void RecentData()
    {
        List<tblAgenda> agd = new List<tblAgenda>();
        StringBuilder sbHeadings = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbData = new StringBuilder();
        List<int> list1 = AgendaManager.SelectByYear();
        if (list1 != null)
        {
            List<int> list = list1.Take(3).ToList<int>();
            int Row = 0;
            string RowCss = "";
            foreach (tblAgenda ob in agd)
            {
                strYears = "";

                if (list.Count > 0)
                {
                    Table tblHead = new Table();
                    TableRow trHead = new TableRow();
                    TableCell tcDvHead = new TableCell();
                    TableCell tcLnkHead = new TableCell();
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Row = 0;
                        List<clsAgenda> listData = new List<clsAgenda>();
                        listData = null;
                        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
                        string stryr = strYears;
                        int intyr = Convert.ToInt32(list[i]);
                        diff = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Year) - Convert.ToInt32(intyr);

                        if (diff == 0 || diff == 1 || diff == 2)
                        {

                            if (drpDepartments.SelectedValue == "-1")
                            {

                                strYears += list[i] + ",";


                                sbHeadings.Append("<div id='dv" + list[i] + "' style='float:left;width:60px;cursor:pointer;'  class='btnclass11'>" + list[i] + "</div><div style='float:left;'>&nbsp;</div>");
                                listData = AgendaManager.SelectAllByYear(Convert.ToInt32(list[i]));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (AgendaManager.IsAgendExistForDeptartment(Convert.ToInt32(list[i]), Convert.ToInt64(drpDepartments.SelectedValue)))
                                {
                                    strYears += list[i] + ",";
                                    sbHeadings.Append("<div id='dv" + list[i] + "' style='float:left;width:60px;cursor:pointer;'  class='btnclass11'>" + list[i] + "</div><div style='float:left;'>&nbsp;</div>");
                                }
                                listData = AgendaManager.SelectAllByYear(Convert.ToInt32(list[i]), Convert.ToInt64(drpDepartments.SelectedValue));
                            }
                            sbData.Append("<table id='tbl" + list[i] + "' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='4' width='885' style='display:none;margin-top:10px;' class='GridBorder' >");
                            sbData.Append("<tr class='GridViewHeaderStyle' >");
                            sbData.Append("<th style='width:380px;height:22px;text-align:left;'>Meeting</th><th style='height:22px;text-align:left;'>Date</th><th style='width:70px;height:22px;text-align:left;'>Time</th><th style='width:70px;height:22px;text-align:left;'>Agenda</th><th style='height:22px;text-align:left;width:120px;'>Web Cast</th><th style='height:22px;text-align:left;width:100px;'>Minutes</th>");
                            sbData.Append("</tr>");
                            foreach (clsAgenda obj in listData)
                            {
                                RowCss = "";
                                if (Row == 1)
                                {
                                    RowCss = "class='GridRow'";
                                }
                                sbData.Append("<tr " + RowCss + ">");
                                sbData.Append("<td >" + obj.Title + "</td>");
                                sbData.Append("<td >" + string.Format("{0:MMM dd, yyyy}", obj.AgendaDate) + "</td>");

                                sbData.Append("<td >" + obj.Time + "</td>");
                                sbData.Append("<td ><a style='color:black;' href='agenda.aspx?id=" + obj.ID + "'>View</a></td>");

                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.WebCast))
                                {
                                    sbData.Append("<td >---</td>");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    sbData.Append("<td ><a style='color:black;' href='" + obj.WebCast + "'>" + obj.WebCastTitle + "</a></td>");
                                }

                                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.MinutesFile))
                                {
                                    sbData.Append("<td >---</td>");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (ob.showThroughBroswer == 1)
                                    {
                                        sbData.Append("<td ><a href='downloadfile.aspx?AgendaMinuteId=" + obj.ID + "' target='_blank'>View</a></td>");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        sbData.Append("<td ><a href='showpdf.aspx?AgendaMinuteId=" + obj.ID + "' target='_blank'>View</a></td>");
                                    }
                                }
                                sbData.Append("</tr>");
                                Row++;
                                if (Row == 2)
                                {
                                    Row = 0;
                                }
                            }
                            sbData.Append("</table>");

                        }
                        else
                            break;
                    }
                    if (strYears.Length > 0)
                    {
                        strYears = strYears.Substring(0, strYears.Length - 1);
                    }
                    strFirstYear = list[0].ToString();
                    tcDvHead.Text = sbHeadings.ToString();

                    if (diff == 1 || diff == 2)
                    {
                        tcLnkHead.Text = "<div class='dvhrfclass'><a href='listagendas.aspx?id=pre' class='link1'>Previous Meetings >></a></div>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tcLnkHead.Text = "";
                    }
                    trHead.Cells.Add(tcDvHead);
                    trHead.Cells.Add(tcLnkHead);
                    tblHead.Rows.Add(trHead);
                    StringWriter sW = new StringWriter();
                    HtmlTextWriter hW = new HtmlTextWriter(sW);
                    tblHead.RenderControl(hW);
                    letHeading.Text = sW.ToString();
                    letData.Text = sbData.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

now the issue is I am getting no values in list1, I have tried using the debugger on the query and found that I can't access the "tblAgenda", its giving an error that: " Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation". I have searched alot but didn't find anything good, my connection string is totally fine because all the other tables are working fine even in "tblAgenda" I can store new agenda from admin panel but I can't retrieve the agendas on front end, what is the issue here?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please find a more meaningful title than pasting the exception message?! Also, please try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I have added the detail in description, I couldn't find any better title. Sorry for that.

Comment: That's just a debugger issue; it has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234762.aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721108/function-evaluation-disabled-because-a-previous-function-evaluation-timed-out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729320/function-evaluation-timed-out-when-examining-variables-in-debug-stepping-through - lmgtfy ...

Comment: but I can't get any value in list1, I am just getting an error that value can not be null when I continue.