# C# Api Last.FM this is error?

Tags: c#, api, xamarin.forms, last.fm, audio

I am writing my small project, which I need to download music album data.

I tried to use last.fm API and I have a strange error :)

```
     public HelpLastFmItemSearch(string albumName)
    {
        //For test
        albumName = "Meteora";


      string _albumsSearchURL =  "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.search&album=" + albumName + "&api_key="+ Api.LastFMKeySingleton.Instance.getApiKey()+"&format=json";
      HttpClient albumSearchClient = new HttpClient();
      var jsonAlbumsSearch = albumSearchClient.GetStringAsync(_albumsSearchURL);
      var deserializeJsonAlbumsSearch = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonAlbumsSearch.Result);
      var deserializeJsonAlbumsSearchTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ViewHelp_Music.AddMusic.LastFm_Api.AlbumSearch.HelpLastFMJsonAlbumsSearch>(jsonAlbumsSearch.Result);
        //Testing !
        var _artistname = deserializeJsonAlbumsSearchTest.Results.Albummatches.Album[0].Artist;
        var _albumname = deserializeJsonAlbumsSearchTest.Results.Albummatches.Album[0].Name;


        string _albumInfoURL = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=" + Api.LastFMKeySingleton.Instance.getApiKey() + "&artist=" + _artistname + "&album=" + _albumname + "&format=json";
        HttpClient albumInfoClient = new HttpClient();
        var jsonAlbumInfo = albumInfoClient.GetStringAsync(_albumInfoURL);
        var deserializeJsonAlbumInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonAlbumInfo.Result);
        var deserializeJsonAlbumInfoTest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ViewHelp_Music.AddMusic.LastFm_Api.AlbumInfo.HelpLastFMJsonAlbumInfo>(jsonAlbumInfo.Result);


        //////Do Poprawy!
    }
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

[Function evaluation timed out when examining variables in debug/stepping through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729320/function-evaluation-timed-out-when-examining-variables-in-debug-stepping-through)

> The most likely cause of this problem is an implicit evaluation of a property or ToString method which causes an issue with the CLR evaluation thread. To verify this turn off implicit evaluation.
>
> - Tools -> Options
> - Debugging
> - Uncheck "Enable property evaluation and
>     other implicit function calls"
>
> Then restart your scenario and see if it works."

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it has not changed anything.

Variables have values, but I get this error and I thought something was wrong in code.